# Some Problems with cache in vTiger CRM

Tags: php, vtigercrm

i wrote a little sh*tcode that loads data from one accounting program in xml format, parses it and adds it to the database, but there is one big problem: the data is displayed on the page itself in CRM, you need to reload the page 2 times, when you first restart the page, the system turns to the cache, and when the second update actually goes to the database, I need somehow using php or js
make it so that it does not access the cache, but access the database

P.S. Version vTigerCRM 7.1 module Products

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are three solution, A) Make dynamic content in your code B) Clear Smarty Cache in your code C) Disable caching in vTiger

If option A works, it is most effective

one is to put a little footer or header in your code that changes the content to let smarty clear cache itself( for example put Date() or a number.

Second solution is to look for SMARTY to clear cache:

```
// clear the entire cache
$smarty->clearAllCache();

// clears all files over one hour old
$smarty->clearAllCache(3600);
```

Third
Look for `PS_SMARTY_CACHE` under Table `prefix_configuration` and set it to **0**

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mason,  I'll definitely try your options and write you the result

Comment: Where should I put the code for 

$smarty->clearAllCache();

- Which table in vtiger we should update PS_SMARTY_CACHE? as there is no table called prefix_configuration